# Filebeat "error loading config file: yaml: did not find expected key"

Tags: filebeat

Im stacked at this issue.

I have an Elasticsearch server with x-pack security enabled. 
A client with Filebeat that is sending outputs to that server.
All is working fin without enabling x-pck security, but whe doing it, in the lient I have this error message.

```
./filebeat test config -v
Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: line 157: did not find expected key
```

The line that causes the error is the "username" and "password". When commented, the config test is OK, but when username and password is uncommented the error appears

```
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ["X.X.X.X:9200"]

  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  #protocol: "http"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "<password_generated_in_server>"
```

Connection is working fine with a XGET request like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://X.X.X.X:9200/_all/_search?q=*&pretty' -u elastic:<password_generated_in_server>
```

Do I need to acivate any x-pack module, option or create the user manually?

My enabled modules are system, elasticsearch and auditd.
Im using a go build for arm in the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Solved.

It seems the configuration file is pretty strict in the syntax... This way is working fine:

```
setup.kibana:
  host: "http://X.X.X.X:5601"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://X.X.X.X:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "<passwd>"
```

Comment: I had the same issue and could only add 1 output.something section. I could not put it on 2 separate lines like:
```
output:
  elasticsearch:
```