# Filebeat 7.9.3 change index is not working and it always creates default filebeat-7.9.3-2020.11.04-000001

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I tried this
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master//change-index-name.html#change-index-name and
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-management-change-index-name-in-filebeat/202876

with  filebeat-7.9.3 and kibana-7.9.2 in windows environment .However in Kibana it doesn't create the indexname that I mentioned in filebeat.yml

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
    - C:\FREESOFT\myfilebeatlogs\*


# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
index: "customindexname-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

Also I tried with

```
index: "myindexname-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.enabled: false
setup.template.name: "myindexname"
setup.template.pattern: "myindexname-*"
```

Kindly help me with this ,I want to create a custom index and insert data to it from Filebeat. The past questions in stack didn't solve my problm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below config works for me and create a index name which I want

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    paths:
      - "/var/log/*.log"
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.overwrite: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["<my-es-host>"]
  index: "foo-%{+yyyy.MM}"
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:elastic}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:elastic}'

setup.template:
  name: 'foo'
  pattern: 'foo-*'
  enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked , I had to change ' to "  because  of '  did not find expected key” which mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415359/filebeat-error-loading-config-file-yaml-did-not-find-expected-key

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva glad it worked  and I was helpful:)